# Comments form action points to different node

Tags: comments

I'm having a very weird problem with comments on a node. I recently upgraded to Drupal 7.12.

Now the comments aren't working right. When a user (registered or anonymous) enters in a node page, the action call of the comment form points to the page URL. But, when the user browses to another page, the action call of the comment form of the new page remains pointing to the previous page! This happened until the browser is closed, or the user logs out.

Could anyone shed some light as to why this is happening?

[Edited]
I just discovered that when I disable de Panel module the issue is not happening. The problem is that all the presentation layer goes to the trash :-( Anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've patched the problem clearing the cache just before the comment form render:

```
    <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
    <?php cache_clear_all('*', 'cache', TRUE); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
```

As I said, seems there is a variable cache problem, and it seems to be on the Ctools module. This is only a patch until the fix comes.

Hope it will be useful.